# How do I globally configure RSpec to keep the '--color' and '--format specdoc' options turned on

Tags: ruby, colors, rspec, configuration-files

How do I set global configuration for RSpec in Ubuntu.

Specifically so, --color and --format specdoc stay turned on, across all my projects (ie every time I run rspec anywhere).

Answer (score 243, accepted):

As you can see in the docs [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files), the intended use is creating `~/.rspec` and in it putting your options, such as `--color`.

To quickly create an `~/.rspec` file with the `--color` option, just run:

```
echo '--color' >> ~/.rspec
```

Comment: `--tty` is also required if you want color even when using pagers.

Comment: Whats the pros/cons to using `.rspec` or `spec_helper.rb`? @shamaoke @christoph

Comment: One big advantage of the `~/.rspec` solution is the portability. E.g. our CI server does not handle color output very well. With the user dir config file, we can easily adopt to different environments.

Comment: One other relevant note is that you can create the .rspec file on a project level and have it apply to just that project.  Just thought some might want to know that here as well.

Comment: Moving my configuration options from spec_helper.rb to .rspec resolved this issue for me.

Comment: @AdamSpiers what's a pager?

Answer (score 154):

One can also use a `spec_helper.rb` file in all projects. The file should include the following:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Use color in STDOUT
  config.color = true

  # Use color not only in STDOUT but also in pagers and files
  config.tty = true

  # Use the specified formatter
  config.formatter = :documentation # :progress, :html,
                                    # :json, CustomFormatterClass
end
```

Any example file must require the helper to be able to use that options.

Comment: The original question asks for a global configuration, this is a project-specific one. Useful, but not the correct answer, unlike abyx's which points to the `.rspec` file.

Comment: A search for info about the RSpec config and formatters brings one to this page, so I appreciated this answer, even if it was for the wrong question :-)

Comment: `color_enabled` is now `color`

Answer (score 12):

In your `spec_helper.rb` file, include the following option:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color_enabled = true
end
```

You then must require in each `*_spec.rb` file that should use that option.

Comment: Hi thank you - would you be able to elaborate on the following: "You then must require in each *_spec.rb file that should use that option." i don't understand.

Comment: Each of your *_spec.rb file usually starts with require "spec_helper", you should not forget this.

Answer (score 6):

If you use rake to run rspec tests then you can edit spec/spec.opts

http://rspec.info/rails/runners.html

Comment: ./spec.opts has been depricated.  Rails 3 wants the file to be named ./.rspec or ~/.rspec

Answer (score 2):

Or simply add `alias spec=spec --color --format specdoc` to your ~/.bashrc file like me.

Comment: This solution is not very portable. Correct answer is @abyx with using `.rspec`, as when its checked in with the project, anyone else getting it will get the same settings.

Comment: But the question was about "global configuration for RSpec in Ubuntu", "across all my projects" not portable nor coop mode.

Comment: Humm, I guess your right, your answer does relate directly to the OP. I was thinking bigger picture, but I still think the better answer was @abyx, if the OP gets used to config projects correctly then others will benefit, maybe not now as he might be workin solo, but good practices are just that. Sorry, bit ranty, just my way of thinking.

Comment: @zzeroo @Ian : Do note that putting the `.rspec` file in the user's home directory (as I mentioned in my answer) works globally for all of the user's invocations of rspec. That is in fact more solid than using aliases, as some gems/other aliases/tools the user might use would not necessarily use the alias

Comment: Now coming back to this question and being a little older and wiser, I would agree that setting the .rspec dot file is now a better option. Updating my approved answer to abyx, thanks so much zzero for answering my question best back in 2010. :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be aware of is the impact of the different ways of running RSpec.

I was trying to turn on the option with the following code in spec/spec_helper.rb -

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.tty = $stdout.tty?
end
```

1. calling the 'rspec' binary directly - or as 'bundle exec rspec' and checking $stdout.tty? will return true.
2. invoking the 'rake spec' task - or as 'bundle exec rake spec' - Rake will invoke rspec in a separate process, and $stdout.tty? will return false.

In the end I used the ~/.rspec option, with just --tty as its contents. Works well for me and keeps our CI server output clean.