# Ruby RSpec : No color on output with a Mac

Tags: ruby, rspec

Developing with my first Mac and I noticed that my Rspec output isn't colorized in my terminal even though I'm using the '`-c`' flag in the command: `bundle exec rspec -c -fd`. Any ideas?

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1819614/119790

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Add the following contents to a .rspec file to your project dir root.

`--color`

Comment: Or, place the .rspec file in your home directory to apply the settings for all projects.

Answer (score 15):

If you're coming here from Google recently, you may notice that Allen Chun's answer gives a `NoMethodError` with `.color_enabled` when using RSpec 3.0 or higher. `.color_enabled` was removed in 3.0: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/Changelog.md#300rc1--2014-05-18

Just change `.color_enabled` to `.color` in `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Use color in STDOUT
  config.color = true

  # other config options here...    

end
```

This worked for me with Ruby 2.1.2p95 on OS X Mavericks 10.9.4.

Answer (score 7):

You can also put the config on the **spec_helper.rb** if you don't want to attach --color every time you run rspec.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
 # Use color in STDOUT
   config.color_enabled = true

 # Use color not only in STDOUT but also in pagers and files
   config.tty = true

 # Use the specified formatter
   config.formatter = :documentation # :progress, :html, :textmate
end
```

Comment: `config.color_enabled = true` didn't work for me, but `config.color = true` did.